# bootstrap function theme-color-level SassError: Undefined variable $theme-color-interval

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Siguiendo la documentacion de bootstrap [aqui](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#functions), intento de utilizar la funcion **theme-color-level** y obtengo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo intento de utilizar de la siguiente manera:

```
// Custom.scss
// Option B: Include parts of Bootstrap

// Bootstrap and its default variables
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

// 1. Include functions first (so you can manipulate colors, SVGs, calc, etc)
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";

// 2. Include any default variable overrides here

// 3. Include remainder of required Bootstrap stylesheets
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// 4. Include any optional Bootstrap components as you like
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";

// 5. Add additional custom code here

@function theme-color-level($color-name: "primary", $level: 0) {
    $color: theme-color($color-name);
    $color-base: if($level > 0, #000, #fff);
    $level: abs($level);
  
    @return mix($color-base, $color, $level * $theme-color-interval);
}

.color-red-50 {
    color: #262626;
    background-color: theme-color-level(#F44336,-10);
}
```

Comment: Estás siguiendo la documentación de la versión 4.0, pero estás trabajando con Bootstrap 5?

Comment: @padaleiana si mi error era ese, lo consegui en [la documentación aqui](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#sass). Colocalo como respuesta para darte el punto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como se menciona en los comentarios, en la [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#color-system) se menciona lo siguiente:

> El sistema de colores que funcionaba con `color-level()` y `$theme-color-interval` fue eliminado en favor de un nuevo sistema de colores. (...)

El porqué de la remoción puede verse en el [pull request en Github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/30622) en el repositorio oficial de Bootstrap (énfasis mío):

> Deshazte de `$theme-color-interval`, *los niveles del 8% son difíciles de calcular*.

Por lo tanto, el error aparece simplemente porque la variable `$theme-color-interval` fue removida en la versión 5 de Bootstrap.